# how to get the prefect url from html encoded url

Tags: c#, asp.net

Folderpath\0\Microsoft%202007\chapter1\images

how can i remove %20 from this url path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
string s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(@"folderpath\Microsoft%202007\chapter1\images");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx

Edit: Sorry I didn't notice the ASP.Net tag in ASp.Net there is a simpler method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx